# ASP.NET and Firefox: gridview SelectedIndexChanged fires twice with HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, firefox, gridview

I have some strange behaviour with gridviews while changing the website from HTTP to HTTPS.
On HTTP everything works fine with all browsers.
On HTTPS the SelectedIndexChanged method is called twice when clicking on this gridview. This only happens in Firefox. All other browsers still work fine.

Some code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLinks" runat="server" 
    CssClass="mydatagrid" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChangedSV" 
    RowStyle-CssClass="spinner rows" 
    Width="100%" 
    Visible ="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# ChooseImage(DirectCast(Eval("Status"), Integer)) %>' 
                    ToolTip='<%# ChooseStatus(DirectCast(Eval("Status"), Integer)) %>' 
                    runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChangedSV(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim id As Integer = CInt(gvLinks.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text)
    .....
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be the cause of this behaviour?
Thanks!!

Comment: You're showing code that references `gvLinks`, but the gridview is `gvRechts`. Is that correct? We might need to see code for `gvLinks`. (?)

Comment: Indeed, thanks for noticing. I think I looked a bit long at that page. I edited the message. Now it gives the right one (gvLinks = gvLeft in English :o) ).

Comment: First guess is the two methods `ChooseImage` and `ChooseStatus` but I think that should be ok. Try removing one just to see. Those are code-behind methods? And how are you selecting rows? Is the `select` button missing?

Comment: Or maybe it's because for each method you're doing two things, the method, and `DirectCast`. I don't know VB very well. Is that the same as CInt? Maybe try that. Could be unrelated to the problem though.

Comment: I removed both chooseImage and chooseStatus and changed them with a fixed image and tooltip, but the problem persists. The rows are selected by clicking on them. There is no select button.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info. The image btn will cause a postback, but that's not https-related. I also don't know how simply clicking on a gridview will do anything at all, unless you're talking about clicking on the image.

Comment: Have you debugged the page to find out what's causing postbacks?

Comment: I'm sorry it took me a while to awnser, but I finally managed to find a solution. Turns out it has nothing to do with the code. Firefox uses HTTP2 instead of HTTP1.1, when the webpage is in HTTPS. When I turned this off in Firefox, the pages worked fine again. I now disabled this in IIS, so everything works fine again everywhere. Thanks again!